# Limiting Cookie Domain Scope in asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, cookies, dns, single-sign-on

I want to set the scope of cookies on subdomain level for single sign on.
I found below piece of code on MSDN to set the scope for cookies @
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.aspx#Y2930

```
Response.Cookies["domain"].Value = DateTime.Now.ToString();
Response.Cookies["domain"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
Response.Cookies["domain"].Domain = "contoso.com";
```

But I don't know where to write this piece of code, in global.asax?
any thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application_PostAuthenticateRequest() is a rather obvious choice I think.

You have authenticated the user at Application_AuthenticateRequest, and you can then go on to modify the cookies domain.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.postauthenticaterequest.aspx